# Limiting min size to html tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem, I need to make tables with unlimited stretching size but I need to define min-width for them so I can see them. When they shrink to like 50% of their original size, they will stop shrinking with browsers window and scroll them to see. I hope you get the idea, here is my html code:

```css
.vnutro {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-width: 50%;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 60px;
}
.th1 {
  width: 25%;
}
.th2 {
  width: 65%;
}
.th3 {
  width: 2%;
}
.th4 {
  width: 2%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="vnutro" style="overflow-x:auto;">

  <a name="1072016">
    <!--tabulka 1-->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="th1">nadpis1</th>
        <th class="th2">nadpis 2</th>
        <th class="th3">nadpis 3</th>
        <th class="th4">nadpis 4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>text1</td>
        <td>text2</td>
        <td>text3</td>
        <td>
          <form action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <a name="1172016">
      <!--tabulka 2-->
      </br>

      <a name="1272016">
        <!--tabulka 3-->

</div>
```

Comment: you have many html syntax errors as well

Comment: anyway columns will stop shrinking when column width fits to its content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample stretch to full width but has a minimum width of 400px, and columns can have same or different width.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/45kdwuej/6/)

```css
table {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  width: 25%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
/* table 2 */
[name="1172016"] ~ table th {
  width: 20%;
}
[name="1172016"] ~ table th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="vnutro" style="overflow-x:auto;">

  <a name="1072016"></a>
  <!--tabulka 1-->
  Table 1
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>nadpis1</th>
      <th>nadpis 2</th>
      <th>nadpis 3</th>
      <th>nadpis 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>text3</td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <a name="1172016"></a>
  <!--tabulka 1-->
  <br>
  Table 2
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>nadpis1</th>
      <th>nadpis 2</th>
      <th>nadpis 3</th>
      <th>nadpis 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>text3</td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, In your mentioned links. There are so much error in your code. So I fix it.

Note: Adjust width according to your need.

**Here is the updated code:**

```
 <div class="vnutro" style="overflow-x:auto;"> 
     <a name="1072016">
     <!--tabulka 1-->
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="500">
         <tr>
             <th class="th1"> nadpis1 </th>
             <th class="th2"> nadpis 2 </th>
             <th class ="th3"> nadpis 3 </th>
             <th class="th4"> nadpis 4 </th>
         </tr>
            <td width="100"> text1 </td>
            <td width="100"> text2 </td>
            <td width="100"> text3 </td>
            <td width="100">
                <form action="">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="box">
                </form>
            </td>
     </table>
     </a>
     <a name="1172016"></a>
     <!--tabulka 2-->
     <br/>
     <a name="1272016"></a>
     <!--tabulka 3-->
 </div>
```

and here is live example on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45kdwuej/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Its almost perfect, i just need to make it expand itself when you make browser window bigger and when I make it smaller i will need to scroll to see everything. Now when i set for example 1000 width, its ok in smaller window but horrible in fullscreen. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, then try adding the following to your CSS to see if that gives you the desired outcome.

```
table {
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp).

Comment: No it doesnt work, i need to stop it from shrinking with browser window. I need it to be responsive with browser window but then it reaches lets say 50%, table headings and table data will stop shrinking with browser and they will stay at that size until I make browser window bigger again.

Comment: And i need to keep width of every single table the same. They will just shrink with browser window until they hit lets say 50% of their original size, and then they will stop shrinking. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, on phone now - will look at this later if you don't have an answer by then

Answer (score 0):

Here is my whole code if it helps you.
HTML: https://paste.ee/p/kkFTh
CSS: https://paste.ee/p/UlbZz